# How do I get from $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1/e)^n}{n!} = e^{1/e}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I get from $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1/e)^n}{n!} = e^{1/e}$$

I am given

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

I am thinking

$$\sum \frac{n!}{n^n}\cdot \frac{1}{n!}$$

But it seems wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x=1/e$.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: But then how do I get from $\sum{\frac{x^n}{n!}}=x$ then?

Comment: @JiewMeng: Huh? That is simply not true. Look at the equation $\sum \frac{x^n}{n!} = e^x$ again.

Comment: @Jiew - loosely speaking, the formula Martin pointed to says that - $\sum \frac{something^n}{n!} = e^{something}$